# Chart.js - Adding Legend in a JSP Page

Tags: javascript, jsp, chart.js

I have a Doughnut Chart, who's code is written in `JSP`.
Now, I want to add a legend to it. But the `legendTemplate` also contains `jsp` in it.

How do I add it ?

```
var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, {legendTemplate: "<ul class=\"<%=name.toLowerCase()%>-legend\" style=\"list-style:none;font-family:HP Simplified;\"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><div style=\"font-size: 12px;\"><div style=\"width:10px;float :left; height:10px;background: <%=segments[i].fillColor%>\"></div><div style=\"padding: 0px 15px;\"><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></div></div></li><%}%></ul>"} );
```

I am getting the following error :

```
An error occurred at line: 58 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/pages/abc/xyz.jsp
name cannot be resolved
55:             
56: 
57:                 var ctx = document.getElementById("assetStatus").getContext("2d");
58:                 var myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, {legendTemplate: "
```

The Value corresponding to the `legendTemplate` has to be a String. How do I escape the `jsp` content ?

Comment: As per stack trace you haven't declared variable `name`.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the legendTemplate first in your server side script block

```
String serverSideLegendTemplate = "<ul class=\"";
serverSideLegendTemplate += name.toLowerCase();
serverSideLegendTemplate += "-legend\" style=\"list-style:none;font-family:HP Simplified;\">";

for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++) {
...
```

And then simply print out the legendTemplate

```
myDoughnutChart = new Chart(ctx).Doughnut(data, {
     legendTemplate: "<%=serverSideLegendTemplate%>"
});
```

This will make it clearer and easier to figure out why the variable can't be resolved (you could have defined it in a separate scope).